# How to using counter in loop migration table? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5.3

My code is like this :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Akun;
use App\Models\Master_lookup;

class MasterLookupsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $i=1;
        Akun::all()->each(function($akun) { 
            $masterLookup = new Master_lookup; 
            $masterLookup->id           = $i;
            $masterLookup->parent_id    = NULL;
            $masterLookup->code         = $akun->kdakun;
            $masterLookup->name         = $akun->nmakun;
            $masterLookup->type         = 'akun';
            $masterLookup->information  = json_encode($akun->kdjenbel);
            $masterLookup->save();
            $i++;
        });
    }
}
```

When executed, there is exist error : undefined variable: i

Is there any people who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the given below:
Create class variable and use it:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Akun;
use App\Models\Master_lookup;

class MasterLookupsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public $i;
    public function run()
    {
        $this->i = 1;
        Akun::all()->each(function($akun) { 
            $masterLookup = new Master_lookup; 
            $masterLookup->id           = $this->i;
            $masterLookup->parent_id    = NULL;
            $masterLookup->code         = $akun->kdakun;
            $masterLookup->name         = $akun->nmakun;
            $masterLookup->type         = 'akun';
            $masterLookup->information  = json_encode($akun->kdjenbel);
            $masterLookup->save();
            $this->i++;
        });
    }
}
```

Based my opinion, class variable is be way to dealing with this.

Comment: thanks. The first way, it worked. but, the second way is not working

Answer (score 0):

Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct when using anonymous functions.
Can you try this one:

```
Akun::all()->each(function($akun) use ($i) { 
        $masterLookup = new Master_lookup; 
        $masterLookup->id           = $i;
        $masterLookup->parent_id    = NULL;
        $masterLookup->code         = $akun->kdakun;
        $masterLookup->name         = $akun->nmakun;
        $masterLookup->type         = 'akun';
        $masterLookup->information  = json_encode($akun->kdjenbel);
        $masterLookup->save();
        $i++;
    });
```